# Reflections tracking erc20

Tags: erc-20

What would be the proper way to track some erc20 token reflections, lets say on a daily base. Would something like that be possible?
I know that with getBalance and getPastEvents I could get the data aggregated, is there some nice way to do it for daily level?

Comment: Take a look at [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/).

Comment: Tnx for info.. I will take a look at it. In your opinion, could it get me there, for BSC also?

Comment: what is a ERC20 token reflection? first hearing of such thing

Comment: Perhaps I have used incorrect wording, if so I do apologize. It's a term that a lot of token uses within its tokenomics. Basically they tax all transactions with certain percentage fee and then redistribute that fee to to token holders and in that way they incentivise holding instead of selling. Hope the explanation helps @Nulik

Comment: ok, well `getBalance()` wont help you with tokens. `getBalance()` is only for getting ETH , not token balance. for token balance `balanceof()` is used, when calling a contract

Comment: `web3.eth.filter()` will give you `Transfer()` logs, which is the standard transfer call, so you can calculate the balance if you know prior balance. if you start from the beginning you rill get prior balance

Comment: there is a website called `ethplorer` and it has a nice api for getting token data